# My returned HTML from a webapi, that has CSS and Javascript, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, css, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I'm following this code [How to return html page from WebApi action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105305/how-to-return-html-page-from-webapi-action)

I do get back HTML, because the result is a partially rendered HTML page, but the references to the CSS and JavaScript are ignored, resulting in a very basic and non-operating webpage.

I copied the code into Brackets to confirm that all of the indenting is correct.  And if I copy the contents to a .HTML file and render that, the CSS and JavaScript run properly.

This suggests that the problem is unrelated to the generated HTML, but something else.  I just don't know what.  The generated code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://example.com/src/rr4h.css'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/images/favicon2.png" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
   ...
   <script src='http://example.com/src/rr4h.js'>
   </script>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure where to look.  The WebApi is "https" but the referenced files are "http" ... Could this be some sort of IIS or browser related security issue?  Something else?

Comment: You really want to reference _example.com_? Have you tried to manually access these urls?

Comment: the HTML works fine if I copy it to a file ... so clearly the references are correct.

Comment: I just tried the call with an http to the webapi instead of the https and that worked ... so it appears to be security related.  Does this mean I need a certificate for site that contains the CSS and JavaScript, or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have https and http you may have mixed content problem this blocks http content, sure.

Try using relative urls in your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/src/rr4h.css'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon2.png" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
   ...
   <script src='/src/rr4h.js'>
   </script>
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

As indicated by one of my comments, the issue is HTTPS vs. HTTP.  To get around this problem, I created a PHP file to read and display the HTML:

```
<?PHP
    $PARAM = $_GET["p"];
    $HTML = file_get_contents('https://example.com?param=' . $PARAM . '&param2=others');
    echo $HTML;
?>
```

That way the PHP doesn't have to be on an SSL certificate and the call is still secured with the https.